# How to restart JS game?

Tags: javascript, reload, restart

I am currently coding a JS game. After the game ends, I want the player to be able to click the "go back to menu" button, be directed to the home page, and then be able to click play and start a new game. The problem I have is that I'm not sure how to reload the game after clicking play. When I click play again, it brings me back to the game over screen with the final score of the previous play.

```
var keys = [];
var health = 100;
var score = 0;
var scene = "menu";
var clicked = false;
keyPressed = function() {
  keys[keyCode] = true;
};
keyReleased = function() {
  keys[keyCode] = false;
};

textFont(createFont("calibri", 35));

//Buttons
var button = function(cJ) {
  this.x = cJ.x;
  this.y = cJ.y;
  this.w = cJ.w;
  this.h = cJ.h;
};
button.prototype.mouseIsOver = function() {
  return (
    mouseX > this.x &&
    mouseX < this.x + this.w &&
    mouseY > this.y &&
    mouseY < this.y + this.h
  );
};
button.prototype.draw = function() {
  noStroke();
  textAlign(CENTER);
  if (this.mouseIsOver() === true) {
    fill(232, 232, 232);
    rect(this.x + 3, this.y - 3, this.w, this.h);
  } else if (this.mouseIsOver() === false) {
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    rect(this.x + 3, this.y - 5, this.w, this.h);
  }
};
var playButton = new button({
  x: width / 2 - 60,
  y: height / 2 + 21,
  w: 120,
  h: 45
});
var howButton = new button({
  x: width / 2 - 60,
  y: 284,
  w: 120,
  h: 45
});
var backButton = new button({
  x: width / 2 - 197,
  y: 365,
  w: 70,
  h: 30
});
var restartButton = new button({
  x: width / 2 - 102,
  y: 250,
  w: 200,
  h: 36
});

var menuC = function() {
  if (howButton.mouseIsOver()) {
    how();
  } else if (playButton.mouseIsOver()) {
    game();
  }
};
var howC = function() {
  if (backButton.mouseIsOver()) {
    menu();
  }
};
var loseC = function() {
  if (restartButton.mouseIsOver()) {
    Program.restart();
  }
};
mouseClicked = function() {
  if (scene === "menu") {
    menuC();
  } else if (scene === "how") {
    howC();
  } else if (scene === "lose") {
    loseC();
  }
};

//TEXT mic.
draw = function() {
  if (scene === "menu") {
    menu();
    //TITLE
    textSize(47);
    fill(41, 207, 182);
    text("ACIDIC RAIN", 207, 147);

    //Buttons
    playButton.draw();
    howButton.draw();

    textSize(30);
    fill(41, 207, 182);
    text("PLAY", 202, 248);
    text("HOW", 202, 311);
  }
  if (scene === "game") {
    game();
  }
  if (scene === "how") {
    how();
    backButton.draw();
    fill(41, 207, 182);
    textSize(17);
    text("BACK", 40, 380);
  }
  if (scene === "lose") {
    lose();
    restartButton.draw();
    fill(0);
    textSize(20);
    text("GO BACK TO MENU", 201, 270);
  }
};
```

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed. Please carefully avoid posting irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because all your variables are declared in the "global" scope (in the beginning of the JS), so calling any method like `game()` or `menu()` just makes these methods reuse the old values from these variables.

I would suggest you wrap the whole code you provided as an example in a "class" (making the variables and the methods - properties of the class). In this way, when a button is clicked, you could easily destroy the instance of the class and recreate a new class in its place (resetting all local variables inside the class instance, causing all previous progress to be erased).

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes